# Javascript regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I need a regex (using Javascript) that matches a string that has any alpha numeric character or the following punctuation characters (`.:;`), such as, there are at least two numbers and  two punctuation characters.

Matching examples:

```
ab0.da;134fd
01.adas:112dd
.dasa;.3123aa
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Give an example for text which should be matched.

Comment: @iamnotmaynard: regex that didn't work...

Comment: Once you figure it out, try using a RegEx "checker" to make sure it matches what you're trying to accomplish: http://regexpal.com

Answer (score -1, accepted):

try this

```
^(?=(.*?\d){2,})(?=([^:;.]*[.:;]){2,}[^:;.]*$)[\w.:;]+$
 -------------- ------------------
        |                |->match further only if there are two punctuation..
        |
        |->match further only if there are atleast two digits
```

Comment: Actually does not work. If i put more than 2 punctuation characters it still matches all.

Comment: I did this `^(?=(.*?\d){2,})(?=(.*?[.:;]){2})[\w.:;]+$` and it matches the whole string if it has more than 2 punctuation...

Comment: make it `(?=([^:;.]*[.:;]){2}[^:;.]*$)`

Comment: Nope... forget it, put the first answer, I will accept it anyway.

Comment: @Moria then you would have to change your question and make `exactly` to `atleast`...;)

Comment: Actually `(?=([^:;.]*[.:;]){2}[^:;.]*$)` works. It was just some weirdness with regexpal ;) Ty

Comment: @Moria `/^(?=(.*?\d){2,})(?=([^:;.]*[.:;]){2,}[^:;.]*$)[\w.:;]+$/.test('a.:;bc');    // false`

Comment: `/(?=([^:;.]*[.:;]){2}[^:;.]*$)/.test('..'); // true`

Comment: @MikeM try to read the question..op says  `at least two numbers and two punctuation characters.`

Comment: Yes, apologies, my mistake, I thought it was at least two _alphanumeric_ characters.